# Error opencv & openframework While cropping image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, openframeworks

I have the following code:

```
IplImage* f( IplImage* src )
{
   // Must have dimensions of output image
   IplImage* cropped = cvCreateImage( cvSize(1280,500), src->depth, src->nChannels );

   // Say what the source region is
   cvSetImageROI( src,  cvRect( 0,0, 1280,500 ) );

   // Do the copy
   cvCopy( src, cropped );
   cvResetImageROI( src );

   return cropped;
}

void testApp::setup(){
    img.loadImage("test.jpg");
    finder.setup("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
    finder.findHaarObjects(img);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
ofRectangle cur;
void testApp::draw(){

    img = f(img);

    img.draw(0, 0);
    ofNoFill();
    for(int i = 0; i < finder.blobs.size(); i++) {
        cur = finder.blobs[i].boundingRect;
        ofRect(cur.x-20, cur.y-20, cur.width+50, cur.height+50);
    }
}
```

It produces an error. I think it's because I don't convert `IplImage` to `ofImage`. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Hi. Can you specify the error message that you're getting?

Comment: |error: cannot convert 'ofImage' to 'IplImage*' for argument '1' to 'IplImage* f(IplImage*)'|

Comment: I don't see a variable of type `ofImage` anywhere in your code. Can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that your instance of img, that your passing to f(), is an instance of ofxCVImage or similar. As far as I know ofx store a protected variable of iplimage, as such you can't cast ofxCVImage to an iplimage.

You might try

```
img = f(img.getCvImage()) // ofxCvImage::getCvImage() returns IplImage
```